# Sharepoint (WSS) templates and missing customisations

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I'm bit of a noob in the sharepoint world, so please bear with any stupidity that might follow...

Our company has a bugs database that is based on Microsofts 40 Sharepoint Templates bugs database, but a few customisations have been made to the deployed template before I started here. I have been tasked with deploying a secondary bugs database for a different project that we are running, however all the customisations made to the original deployment will still apply. So rather than deploy the original MS template again and attempt to recreate all the customisations, I though it would be easier to save a template from the existing site. I did not included content when creating this template, as the existing records are irrelevant to the new database, plus there is a large amount of data and sharepoint complains about the size limit being exceeded.

After creating a new site through central admin, using the custom template I created, I have a problem with the Resolve Bug (Resolve.aspx) screen. It doesnt display anything but the  header, no form fields and no buttons. If I look at the site with Sharepoint designer, it indicates that I have altered this file but I haven't made any changes to it. If I look at it in desgin view, it does look empty and doesnt have the default web part items that appear if I look at any of the other pages. I have tried to copy code out of the original sites aspx page into the new one, but that just causes the page to say it's "Unable to display this Web Part". I even tried unzipping the orignal templates wsp file and copying the entire Resolve.aspx into the new site, but to no avail.

Has anybody had a similar problem before or got any thoughts on how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: It appears that somebody (that left the company before I joined) made some customisations to the resolve.aspx page. As far as I can tell this may have caused the customised webpart to be stored in the wss_content DB, and the orignal webpart details to be removed from the aspx file. When I created a new site from the generated template the customisations stored in the DB were not included. Is there a way for me to retrieve these customisations directly from the DB and copy them into the new site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the webparts that display your information are looking at fields that do not exists exactly as they do in your other site.

Try looking at the page on the first site and manually adding the required webparts.
Then any configurations will be specific to the new site.

Comment: Ok, I tried exporting the webpart from the original site and then importing it into the new site and page but now it displays the following message instead _"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer."_ Though if I open it in Sharepoint Designer there's a lot of CDATA code that I can't really decipher..

Comment: You may have to recreate from scratch instead